# PYMYSQL ERROR pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax ")

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-rds, pymysql

Here is the full error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop/Work/RDS_LAMDA_Stuff/RDS_Node_Stuff/test.py", line 26, in <module>
    handler()
  File "Desktop/Work/RDS_LAMDA_Stuff/RDS_Node_Stuff/test.py", line 17, in handler
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Reads')
  File "Desktop/Work/RDS_LAMDA_Stuff/RDS_Node_Stuff/pymysql/cursors.py", line 148, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "Desktop/Work/RDS_LAMDA_Stuff/RDS_Node_Stuff/pymysql/cursors.py", line 310, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "Desktop/Work/RDS_LAMDA_Stuff/RDS_Node_Stuff/pymysql/connections.py", line 548, in query
    self._affected_rows = self._read_query_result(unbuffered=unbuffered)
  File "Desktop/Work/RDS_LAMDA_Stuff/RDS_Node_Stuff/pymysql/connections.py", line 775, in _read_query_result
    result.read()
  File "Desktop/Work/RDS_LAMDA_Stuff/RDS_Node_Stuff/pymysql/connections.py", line 1156, in read
    first_packet = self.connection._read_packet()
  File "Desktop/Work/RDS_LAMDA_Stuff/RDS_Node_Stuff/pymysql/connections.py", line 725, in _read_packet
    packet.raise_for_error()
  File "Desktop/Work/RDS_LAMDA_Stuff/RDS_Node_Stuff/pymysql/protocol.py", line 221, in raise_for_error
    err.raise_mysql_exception(self._data)
  File "Desktop/Work/RDS_LAMDA_Stuff/RDS_Node_Stuff/pymysql/err.py", line 143, in raise_mysql_exception
    raise errorclass(errno, errval)
pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Reads' at line 1")
```

For context here is my code

```
from multiprocessing import connection
import pymysql
from pymysql.cursors import Cursor

# RDS config
endpoint = '********'
username = '********'
password = '********'
database_name = '*********'

#connection config

connection = pymysql.connect(host=endpoint,user=username,passwd=password,db=database_name)

def handler():
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Reads')

    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
        print("{0} {1} {2} {3}".format(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]))



handler()
```

I have 2 other tables in my database which work fine when i query them however this table seems to be the only one causing an error.

Feel free to ask for more if this is too vague

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's worth checking [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-R) in cases like this - and Reads is a reserved word therefore must be backticked - better still don't use reserved words or you will forever have to remember to backtick in code..

Comment: Thanks for the help and quick response a simple name change did the trick